# Can we empty out [null]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, tag-cleanup-request

Seriously, I have no idea what [null](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/null) is for - null characters, null processes, errors, null strings, nil, nada, nothing, [blank](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/blank), empty?

I really don't see the point of `null` when it's not specific enough to determine what is null. Maybe a retag is in order?

Comment: Only 19 questions have this tag.

Comment: It's a Seinfeld tag--a tag about nothing.

Comment: I'm tempted to edit and add the null tag.....

Comment: The tags are stored in a list. The [null] tag is obviously needed to terminate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know who did most of the retagging, but I just nulled the [null](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/null) tag from the last six questions that had it.

RIP [null](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/null): 2010-2016.

Comment: Awesome, it can go and hang out with "untagged"